# Why does PowerShell's Start-Process need -passthru on one PC but not another?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script I had this line:

```
Start-Process firefox | Wait-Process 180
```

which worked fine. However, when I ported the script to another PC it failed. I had to change it to

```
Start-Process -passthru firefox | Wait-Process 180
```

because, by default, Start-Process produces no output. My question is, how was the line working on the first PC?

Both PCs are running Windows XP SP3, and both PowerShells claim that $host.version is 2 0 -1 -1. I have the PowerShell Community Extensions installed on the first PC, but I can't see anywhere there that modifies the Start-Process cmdlet. Also, the use of Firefox is irrelevant: the same thing happens with other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC Start-Process was introduced in PSCX v1.0. Is that the version you have installed? PowerShell's Start-Process is a v2 command.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I obviously didn't look closely enough at the PSCX release notes. Interestingly I've just noticed that 'Get-Command Start-Process' returns only one result, but 'Get-Help Start-Process' shows the PowerShell version and the PSCX one.

Comment: That is because command names are unique.  The last one loaded wins (in this case, PSCX).